# Fat binaries in iOS

Tags: xcode, ios7, 64-bit

Is it possible yet to build 32bit and 64bit 'fat' binaries for iOS? My understanding was that this was coming down the line but I can't see an obvious way to do it in the latest update to Xcode?

I want my application to run in 64bit mode on 5S and 32bit on 5 and below (obviously),

I did read the docs:

*Applications can now target iOS 5.1.1 and later while building for 64-bit using the “Standard architecture (including 64-bit)” build setting. This produces an Archive for the App Store with a single binary containing both 32-bit and 64-bit components. During development and testing, you must build only 32-bit when targeting an iOS 5.1.1 device (this is the default in Xcode).*

However this is not clear regarding if it's possible to build a 32 and 64bit fat binary with a target deployment of iOS 7
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Make sure that you turn off "Build for Active Architecture Only" first. Doing this in XCode 5 and using Standard Architecture will produce a binary with armv7 and armv7s code, so adding 64bit support should do the same.

If you have any third party libraries, be sure to check for updates that support the new devices.