# Making Multi-Architecture iOS and Mac OS Frameworks

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios8

I'm having issues developing a Framework with the new Xcode 6 Dynamic Framework target.

Basically, I need the same result as the old way ([Explained very well in this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)).

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629985/fat-binaries-in-ios), but the problem is that the framework only produces a couple of ARM binaries. I need to have the i386/x86_64 binaries in there, as well, so it will be a complete framework.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something. Does anyone have a clue for this clueless person?

Comment: Hmm...The more I look into this, the more I realize that the new target isn't really what I need. Looks like I'll still be running command-line builds and composing with lipo.

Comment: I'll have to get around to seeing if something like this can also be done with dyLibs. Not a priority. The method in my answer works very well, despite the rather petty downvote. It's an accurate and extremely relevant answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, looks like this isn't very interesting to most folks.

Ah, well. I did get it going with a better version of the Wenderlich script, which I'll post here.

This has the significant advantage of being a "First Class Citizen" framework; not the iOS8-only dynamic version produced by the new target.

```
#! /bin/sh

# This was cribbed from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

# This script will build a multiplatform framework for the project referenced from the $FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME environment variable.
# This variable needs to be set as a user-defined value in the build settings of this target (an aggregate target that just runs this script).
# The project must have a static lib target, with the exact name defined by $FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME, and the output from that target needs to be
# a static lib that is "lib${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.a". The static lib target needs to have a "Debug" and a "Release" configuration, with the
# debug configuration embedding symbols/profiling information (as opposed to a separate DSYM file).
# No stripping should be done for non-debug in either configuration (but it is advised to strip debug symbols in "Release").
# The aggregate target should also define the $DELIVERABLE_DIRECTORY environment variable. This is a relative POSIX path from the ${BUILD_DIR}
# location, to a place that the user wants to deliver the framework. The script will create a "Framework" directory there, with a "Debug" and
# a "Release" directory; each containing a copy of the framework.
# The static lib target needs to create a "Headers" directory with exported headers, and a "Resources" directory (even if it is empty).

set -e

# If we're already inside this script then die
if [ -n "$MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
export MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS=1

# This function actually runs the static lib target build, in the configuration requested.
# INPUT: SDK, configuration (either "Debug" or "Release"), target name

function build_static_library
{
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    -configuration "${2}" \
    -target "${3}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}

# This function will build the iphoneos and iphonesimulator versions of the framework, and will
# use lipo to merge them together into a "fat" binary that contains x86 and ARM code.
# It will also copy the headers and the resources for the framework, so the static lib target needs to create
# a "Headers" directory with exported headers, and a "Resources" directory (even if it is empty).
# INPUT: configuration (example: "Release" or "Debug").

function buildTwoArchitectures
{
    # 1 - Extract the platform (iphoneos/iphonesimulator) from the SDK name
    if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
        SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
        echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
        exit 1
    fi

    # 2 - Extract the version from the SDK
    if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]; then
        SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
        echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphoneos" ]; then
        OTHER_PLATFORM="iphonesimulator"
    else
        OTHER_PLATFORM="iphoneos"
    fi

    # Build the other platform.
    build_static_library "${SDK_PLATFORM}${SDK_VERSION}" "${1}" "${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}"
    build_static_library "${OTHER_PLATFORM}${SDK_VERSION}" "${1}" "${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}"

    BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${1}-${SDK_PLATFORM}"
    OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${1}-${OTHER_PLATFORM}"

    # Create the path to the real Headers dir
    mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
    mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Resources"

    # Create the required symlinks
    ln -sfh A "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/Current"
    ln -sfh Versions/Current/Headers "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Headers"
    ln -sfh Versions/Current/Resources "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Resources"
    ln -sfh "Versions/Current/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}"

    # Copy the public headers into the framework
    cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Headers/" "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"

    # Copy the resources into the framework.
    cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Resources/" "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Resources"

    # Join the 2 static libs into 1 and push into the .framework
    lipo    -create "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libNKPTPF.a" "${OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libNKPTPF.a" \
            -output "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}"

    # Move the resultant framework to our delivery location.
    rm -drf "${BUILD_DIR}/${DELIVERABLE_DIRECTORY}/Framework/${1}/"
    mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}/${DELIVERABLE_DIRECTORY}/Framework/${1}/"
    mv -f "${BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_PRODUCT_NAME}.framework" "${BUILD_DIR}/${DELIVERABLE_DIRECTORY}/Framework/${1}/"
}

# Make it so, numbah one...
buildTwoArchitectures "Debug"
buildTwoArchitectures "Release"
```

Comment: this makes a static framework though -- while the post title talks about dynamics

Comment: Um...I'm the poster. I answered my own question. Did you actually READ what I wrote before hitting the "downvote" button? Holy cow.

Comment: a) I saw you were the poster, b) I even said what was the issue. :the topic speaks of a dynamic framework and I only said that this answer doesn't fit the question. [I actually searched for a way to do this with dynamic libs] c) don't take it so fricking seriously ;) -- oh and I wish I was younger -- and do try to be less condescending as it surely won't help you anywhere

Comment: I deleted my sarcastic comment. Apologies for being cranky. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Oh, by the way. This will also build frameworks that will run on Mac OS X, as long as you don't reference any iOS-specific stuff in it. I use it to provide a full WiFi/BSD Sockets/PTP-IP stack for iOS and Mac OS X.